# Python: Set a string as the default of a nested dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to loop through a list of words and nest each letter of the word and then default the last letter to the original word.

```
    words = ['paste', 'pasta', 'pasha']
    self.T = {}
    for word in words:
        current_dict = self.T
        for letter in word:
            current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(letter, {})
```

This outputs:

```
{'p': {'a': {'s': {'t': {'e': {}, 'a': {}}, 'h': {'a': {}}}}}}
```

but the output I want is:

```
{'p': {'a': {'s': {'t': {'e': 'paste', 'a': 'pasta'}, 'h': {'a': 'pasha'}}}}}
```

how do I avoid this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

Comment: You never assign the final key. What is surprising you about the result?

Comment: This looks like a strange implementation of a trie btw. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Where in the code are you getting that error?

Comment: Your question is very inconsistent. You show an output but also show an error. I know that the code you show makes the output, but in that case you need to show the other code. The error is pretty straightforward. You get to a `str` leaf, but try to call `setdefault` on it.

Comment: please give preference to put minimal code examples that are executable. If the snippet is part of a method in a class, just paste a fake class and method around the snippet.

Comment: the error occurs when I change the default to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = ['paste', 'pasta', 'pasha']
self.T = {}
for word in words:
    current_dict = self.T
    for index, letter in enumerate(word):
        if index < len(word) - 1:
            current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(letter, {})
    current_dict[letter] = word
```

Comment: this creates an output with an added last letter:

Comment: {'p': {'a': {'s': {'t': {'e': {'e': 'paste'}, 'a': {'a': 'pasta'}}, 'h': {'a': {'a': 'pasha'}}}}}}

Comment: sorry - fixed now